# How do i get the nav bar dropdown menu to overlap the body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I'm trying to get the dropdown menu on the navbar to overlap the body. I have tried z-index: 1; but the drop down menu is still cover by the body, How do I get the dropdown menu to overlap the body?

Also when I try to get have the navbar in mobile mode the menu is not align with the navbar, how do I get it align with the nav bar?

Thanks for your help!

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('nav ul li > a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.dropdown').toggle();
      $('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.dropdown').hide();
    });
    $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    $('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('nav ul').toggle();
});
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
*, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Navbar */
nav {
float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #008000;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 1px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
}

.mobile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: static;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  #toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    top: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
  }

  #toggle span,
  #toggle span:before,
  #toggle span:after {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }

  #toggle span:before {
    top: -10px;
  }

  #toggle span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
  }

  #toggle.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  #toggle.active span:before,
  #toggle.active span:after {
    top: 0;
  }

  #toggle.active span:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  #toggle.active span:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-transform: none;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Body */
.body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  width:90%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background-color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:.5em;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

.item {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  padding:.5em;
  border:1px solid #333;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
}

.item p {
  min-height:3em;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
  margin:.5em 0 0 0;
  font-size:.9em;
  text-align:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:33.3%;
  }

}


@media screen and (max-width:800px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:50%;
  }

  .item p {
  font-size:.8em;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="brand">
        <a href="#!">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <div class="mobile">
          <a id="toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a></li>
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
            <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="body">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `z-index` here. The problem is you added `overflow:hidden` to `.container`. And you have a `.container` inside `.navigation`.

```
.navigation .container {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

will fix it.

---

You might want to remove `z-index: -1` from `.body`.

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('nav ul li > a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.dropdown').toggle();
      $('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.dropdown').hide();
    });
    $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    $('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('nav ul').toggle();
});
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
*, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Navbar */
nav {
float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #008000;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 1px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
}

.mobile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: static;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  #toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    top: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
  }

  #toggle span,
  #toggle span:before,
  #toggle span:after {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }

  #toggle span:before {
    top: -10px;
  }

  #toggle span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
  }

  #toggle.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  #toggle.active span:before,
  #toggle.active span:after {
    top: 0;
  }

  #toggle.active span:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  #toggle.active span:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-transform: none;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Body */
.body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width:90%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background-color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:.5em;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

.item {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  padding:.5em;
  border:1px solid #333;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
}

.item p {
  min-height:3em;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
  margin:.5em 0 0 0;
  font-size:.9em;
  text-align:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:33.3%;
  }

}
nav > li:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:50%;
  }

  .item p {
  font-size:.8em;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:100%;
  }

}
.navigation .container {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="brand">
        <a href="#!">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <div class="mobile">
          <a id="toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a></li>
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
            <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="body">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can help but the code is really messy and you need to refactor this asap.

General idea when creating navigation or any other type of overlay is:

1. Separate whole overlay into html element, with nav, menu icon and logo etc...
2. Position it fixed and make it stretched with all direction set to 0
3. Make only one .open-overlay class with should give your overlay display block and your body overflow hidden (this might not be needed, depend on what you want to achieve)
4. Use js to add that class on click, so this should all be one one line of code if you don't count code for adding event listener.

**Please note**: For making your body non scrollable there is a lot of better option then to set overflow to hidden, please search stack for it.

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('nav ul li > a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.dropdown').toggle();
      $('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.dropdown').hide();
    });
    $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    $('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('nav ul').toggle();
});
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
*, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Navbar */
nav {
float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #008000;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 1px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
}

.mobile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: static;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  #toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    top: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
  }

  #toggle span,
  #toggle span:before,
  #toggle span:after {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }

  #toggle span:before {
    top: -10px;
  }

  #toggle span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
  }

  #toggle.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  #toggle.active span:before,
  #toggle.active span:after {
    top: 0;
  }

  #toggle.active span:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  #toggle.active span:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-transform: none;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Body */
.body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  width:90%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background-color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:.5em;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

.item {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  padding:.5em;
  border:1px solid #333;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
}

.item p {
  min-height:3em;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
  margin:.5em 0 0 0;
  font-size:.9em;
  text-align:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:33.3%;
  }

}


@media screen and (max-width:800px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:50%;
  }

  .item p {
  font-size:.8em;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="brand">
        <a href="#!">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <div class="mobile">
          <a id="toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a></li>
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
            <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a id="home" href="#!">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="body">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have. You haven't answered the question. The question is why when page is full size the dropdown doesn't overlap the content. You're assuming he asks for the `box-shadow` not to be cut anymore, which would be fixed by simply removing the `background-color` from `nav li a`. All refactoring you propose was not required. Maybe this code is not for production, but for learning. If you want to teach you need to answer one question at a time. The current question, preferably. The above is *"work-for-free"* and is not welcome on [so] because it's not really useful on the long run.

Comment: Then make a comment about and will take a look again, it is ok not to get it right. Why are people so quick on downvotes. Also there is no such thing as "full size" mentioned in question.

Comment: You haven't even look at what i did right? 
Anyway, we are here to help, ofc that I will do my best to help, this is why I told him that this need to be refactor since it is really bad, when you are a beginner you actually don't know that you are writing bad code. And that is fine as long as you ask and someone (like me, not you) is trying to educate.

Comment: I added "full size" it to help you understand it, as a helping hand. I'm sure now, that I told it to you, you can see it when you read the question, too. The voting system is a quick way to show approval or disapproval towards a particular answer. When I see an answer that I think is wrong, I down-vote it. When I have time, I explain why. When not, not. You can delete answers and get your rep back, if it's that's important to you. I hoped my intervention and help here were more valuable.

Comment: I read all the text, I don't want and don't care about the code. I believe you are wrong in your approach because you just go: "do A, B and C". You don't even consider explaining why it is better as you propose. That's what is important. Therefore, even if everything you did is really much better for current example, not explaining why this is better makes is almost useless for anyone wanting to learn.

Comment: "I read all the text, I don't want and don't care about the code."
Good night mate...

Comment: In my personal opinion, using code without understanding it is meaningless and has no value. You don't get better at coding if someone else writes code for you. You only get better when someone explains why it's better. Have a good night yourself.

Comment: In the code I posted I did the same as what I explained in the answer so let just stop here I don't care, stop spamming my inbox.